# Intellij Ant - javac does not compile files, no error or message

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant

I've been trying to compile a project using Ant in Intellij, when the javac task runs, there is no output, but no error. If I run ant manually with the same build file, everything compiles correctly and I have output from javac.

This is the task in build.xml:

`<javac classpathref="libClassPath" srcdir="${sourceFolderPath}" destdir="${classFilePath}" verbose="true" debug="true"/>`

This is the output from intellij's ant:

```
build.xml
property
taskdef
fileset
path
property
taskdef
taskdef
compileClasses
echo
===== Compiling src files C:\Users\user\project\Build/../src
echo
Class file Path: C:\Users\user\project\Build/dist/classes
mkdir
Created dir: C:\Users\user\project\Build\dist\classes
javac
```

Show all output is turned on. Not sure what I'm missing. I've reinstalled intellij as well, to no avail.

Comment: does `javac2` perform properly

Comment: Thanks @Ishnark, using javac2 forced the error to be written to the console. There was a problem with one of the jars I needed to add to the ant/lib directory, looks like it was zipped incorrectly? Once I replaced it with a proper one, it worked just fine.
I feel this error shouldn't have been hidden using the normal javac target, but at least I can compile everything now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was an issue with one of the jars in the ant/lib directory. One of them had been zipped incorrectly, or been corrupted. Once I replaced this jar, everything started working.

The only way I was able to find this issue was by using the javac2 task from IDEA. For some reason, this error was hidden by intellij when using the normal javac task.

Thanks, @Ishnark for your help.